# timer object for execute task repeatly: when to call cancel()

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer

I'm going to use Timer object for execute periodically an AsyncTask, and that object live inside a Fragment. Api claims

> When a timer is no longer needed, users should call cancel()

this means that Timer objec continue his life also when i destroy Fragment that creates it, so i should call explicit cancel when Fragment is destroyed?

Comment: yes you have to call cancel method explicitly in onDestroy

Comment: are you using a CountDownTimer or Timer class , add some code of your fragment and timer

Comment: yes, you can call cancel() on fragment's onPause() method. This is best approach to prevent using unnecessarily resources. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should cancel the timer in the `onDestroy()` method like this :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(timer != null && isTimerRunning) {
           timer.cancel(); // for CountDownTimer
           timer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```